# Write theorem in MathJax?

Tags: mathjax

Is there way to create something like the `amsthm` theorem-environment in MathJax? I believe that package is not supported.

I added `amsthm.js` in `default.html` and nothing happens.

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
    MathJax.Hub.Config({ 
      TeX: { 
        extensions: ["amsthm.js", "AMSmath.js","AMSsymbols.js", "autobold.js"],
      }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

No. Well, technically, you could write an extension that does this but it's not what MathJax is for.

To quote [the mathjax documentation](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#mathjax-tex-and-latex-support)

> Note that the TeX input processor implements **only** the math-mode macros of TeX and LaTeX, not the text-mode macros. MathJax expects that you will use standard HTML tags to handle formatting the text of your page; it only handles the mathematics. So, for example, MathJax does not implement `\emph` or `\begin{enumerate}...\end{enumerate}` or other text-mode macros or environments. You must use HTML to handle such formatting tasks. If you need a LaTeX-to-HTML converter, you should consider other options.

Comment: So can you suggest an alternative? Just simple stuff to get the usual format of a theorem/lemma/proof/end of proof.

Comment: That's unfortunately not very simple stuff. LaTeX's text mode is its own beast and a complete programming language. There are many LaTeX to HTML converters out there and their priorities differ considerably. Pandoc and latexml may give you an idea for the breadth of the spectrum.

Answer (score 0):

Manually insert HTML bold and italic fonts; hard-code counters.

```
<b>Theorem 1.1</b> (Pythagoras) <i>The sum of the squares on the legs of a right triangle equals the square on the hypotenuse.</i>

<i>Proof:</i><br>
Look it up.
<br>&#x25A1;
```

**Theorem 1.1** (Pythagoras) *The sum of the squares on the legs of a right triangle equals the square on the hypotenuse.*

*Proof:*
Look it up.

□